# Logstash event field reference is not working

Tags: logging, logstash, elk

I have a small event that I want to pass to logstash from python:

```
{
   "@timestamp":"2022-06-13T16:48:39.422Z",
   "@version":"1",
   "message":"Something happened",
   "host":"Not important",
   "path":"Not important",
   "tags":[
      
   ],
   "type":"logstash",
   "level":"INFO",
   "logger_name":"python-logstash-logger",
   "product":"MySoftware"
}
```

I want to extract the "product" field from my event so I can use it later in Kibana.

I've already tried this config:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "Product" => "%{product}" }
    }
}
```

I get `Product = %{product}` as output, but I want to get `Product = MySoftware`.
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

When you get `Product = %{product}` as output, that mean field 'product' does'nt exist.

Before setting `"Product"` verify if `"product"` exist.

```
filter {
  if [product] {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "Product" => "%{[product]}" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But the message above definitely has a "product" field. Why doesn't my filter recognize it? I tried your solution, and unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: maybe the data is not in json format when logstash receives it but rather in string.
If this is the case you have to transform it into json before any operation
can you do a data capture on kibana?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the problem was in the client for logstash for python that I was using. It's called python-logstash, runs pretty slow (compared to my solution), and creates unnecessary fields for me. Perhaps I just didn't figure out how to use it properly.

I decided to use the tcp-handler instead, and send the json with the fields I wanted.

Now my logstash configuration looks like this:

```
input {
    tcp {
       port => 5000
       codec => json
    }
}
```

There is no "filter" field because kibana automatically interprets all json keys as available fields.

Here is minimal working example on Python:

```
import json
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 5000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((host, port))
    data = {'message': 'hi', 'product': 'mySoftware'}
    sock.send(str.encode(json.dumps(data)))
```